# What is the best way to setup email hosting on different server

Tags: mx-record, ns-record

we want to use server "xyz" for emails and meanwhile keep the site on server "abc"

we have entered both name server records into godaddy.
ns1.abc.com
ns2.abc.com
ns1.xyz.com
ns2.xyz.com

**In server "abc" cPanel** (procedure-abc)
Set Email routing to Remote Mail Exchanger
created a "mx" record mail.mydomain.com
created a "A" record for "mail.mydomain.com" and point that to IP of server "xyz"

**In server "xyz" cPanel** (procedure-xyz)
Point the "A" Records of "mydomain.com" and point that to IP of server "abc"

Please tel me what is the best way? 
Option1 - Setting up both name server and follow the both setting above
Option2 - Setting up only "ns1.abc.com" and follow only procedure-abc
Option3 - Setting up only "ns1.xys.com" and follow only procedure-xyz

Comment: I think you should elaborate your question. _to use server "xyz" for emails_ means send or receive emails? Do you want to receive emails sent to abc, xyx or both of them? Do you want to send emails as xyz or abc?

Comment: I want to send and receive email for "info@mydomain.com". I guess once I changed the Email routing to Remote Mail Exchanger (procedure-abc) mail server "xyz" responsible for sending and receiving emails. Please correct me if I wrong. I thing emails accounts created in server "abc" no longer work

Comment: All the DNS records must be on all the authoritative servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you want to send and receive email for "*@mydomain.com" through xyz, abc domain NS records don't play any role at all.

Incoming and outgoing traffic must be configured separately.

**In order to receive email for "*@mydomain.com" through xyz, just setup DNS records:**

1. Create a mydomain.com MX record pointing to, let's say mail.xyz.com
2. Create a mail.xyz.com A record pointing to your SMTP host IP address (xyz server)

**In order to send email from "*@mydomain.com" through xyz, MTA routing must be configured:**

1. Configure abc host to route outgoing emails through server xyz
2. Configure server xyz to allow SMTP relay for mydomain.com.

Comment: I have no idea where/how to configure the following

    1.Configure abc host to route outgoing emails through server xyz
    2.Configure server xyz to allow SMTP relay for mydomain.com.

Comment: I suggest you to first try to understand _what_ and then look for _where/how_. So the first step is to know which MTA are you using, then to know how to configure it. Example: _what_ --> Postfix, _where_ --> _/etc/postfix/main.cf_ and _/etc/postfix/master.cf_

Answer (score 0):

You have to add records to all authoritative servers for `mydomain.com` - in your example which ones are authoritative? abc or xyz?

You need to set:

- record A for `mydomain.com` which points to abc server,
- record A for `mail.mydomain.com` which points to xyz server,
- record MX with `mail.mydomain.com` in it.

Comment: I guess both server is authoritative as its both name server is configured for mydomain.com

Comment: You can use `dig` to make sure.